# Regex Matching a URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I'm not looking for any URL, and i think im close, but not close enough. I need a regex, that works with JS, and matches:
http OR https
portlandonline.com OR portlandoregon.gov

And then *anything* after that EXCEPT spaces.

I've come up with this so far, but it's not working, but it's close:

```
https?://portland+[online\.com|oregon\.gov][./\d\w]+
```

The main issue is that it matches:
`http://portlandon` and `http://portlandor` i want to make sure that it is a real, valid, URL with the specs i have above.

I'm still new at this, but ive spent like a solid hour working this out and reading through http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Thanks!

Comment: Try `https?://portland(online\.com|oregon\.gov)\S*`

Comment: Thanks you rock, what does the capital \S* do?

Comment: Well, as requested, it matches anything but spaces ;)

Comment: OH! i see, perfect thanks so basically \S = any non-whitespace character and then * means zero or more of those?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/https?://portland(?:online\.com|oregon\.gov)[^\s]*/
```

Comment: '?:' just prevents the parenthesis from capturing the match. Since you don't need to capture the value, it saves a little memory :)

Comment: Other than that the only difference between mine and @Pumbaa80's is he used \S where I used [^\s]. His is better in that regard if anything to save on typing :)

Comment: Yeah, i didn't realize how flexible RegEx is. I thought it was super strict and all you guys have sorta different ways of doing it... 3 actually haha

Answer (score 0):

```
/http(s)?:\/\/portland+(online\.com|oregon\.gov)(.*)?/
```

Conditionals and optionals should be in round brackets, and you needed to escape the slashes.

EDIT - updated to also capture the trailing path.

Answer (score -1):

```
https?://portland(?:online|oregon)\.(?:gov|com)[./\d\w]*
```

Comment: online.com and oregon.gov.  2 domains not 4 I think.

Comment: This also matches portlanonline.gov - not sure if he wants that or not.